# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on custom domain on Amazon Amplify/Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-amplify

I am trying to serve a website on AWS amplify. The custom domain is showing a SSL certificate, but when I try to load the website, it says This site can’t provide a secure connection - sent an invalid response ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I have definitely verified the domain on Amplify and Route 53. But the website ceases to cooperate. I have asked some friends to try it and it works but I am afraid they are seeing cached versions. The domain is https://www.mupwebdesign.com.

The amplifyapp.com website is loading just fine, but this custom domain one doesn't.

Comment: If you could check the domain and take a screenshot and post it here it would be appreciated. It could be my ISP as I performed a health check on AWS and it came back as healthy.

Comment: This error often happens with Chrome when you have changed the security configuration of your site (SSL certificate, etc). Restart your browser and press CTRL-F5 to reload the page. Also verify with a different browser.

Comment: Hi John. I am using a USB tether to provide my PC with internet from my phone. I am experiencing the same issues on my phone too. I am beginning to think it's my mobile network is the problem. I followed your steps to no avail. Did you click the link? If so, did it load for you?

Comment: Your site appears fine in my browser - Chrome 80. Try a difference browser that has not been to your site.

Comment: Hi John. I just waited and it fixed itself. Thanks for the support. All the best.